# jquery ajax: doctype syntax error and $ is not defined error on remote server

Tags: jquery, ajax, cakephp

My jquery ajax code is working fine on my local server. However, it is not working on the remote server justhost.com. This is driving me nuts. :( Can someone point out on where i'm going wrong?

[Merry Flowers](http://www.merryflowers.com/) is the link to my website. When u go to the website with firebug on, u will be able to see the below mentioned errors.

When I try to debug with firebug, i'm getting the following 2 errors:

i'm getting a syntax error on the following line:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

I tried with different doctypes and I was still getting the same errors.

i'm getting "$ is not defined error" on the following line:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Google chrome developer tool's errors:

```
    Resource interpreted as Script but transferred with MIME type text/html: "http://www.merryflowers.com/js/jquery.js".
jquery.js:1Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
home:8Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
```

When i click on network tab for chrome developer tool,

```
jquery.js's type is text/html not application/javascript. While the other javascript files are of type application/javascript.
```

cakephp's original default.ctp code after all the corrections as requested by Lazerblade:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 

Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>

<?php
 echo $this->Html->charset();
 ?>
<title>
    <?php  __('Merry Flowers Montessori'); ?>
    <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
</title>
<?php
    //echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
    echo $this->Html->css('cake.generic');  //link to cake.generic.css will be 

placed in $scripts_for_layout
        echo $this->Html->css('navbar.css'); 
        echo $this->Html->script('jquery.js'); //Include jquery library
/*      echo $this->Html->script('swfobject.js');
*/

    echo $this->Session->flash();
    echo $this->Session->flash('email');
    echo $scripts_for_layout;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
   //var j=jQuery.noConflict();
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#MerryParentEmail").change(function(){
        //txt=$("#MerryParentEmail").val();
        email_id=$("#MerryParentEmail").serialize();
        //alert(txt);
        $.post("/students/get_parent_info",email_id,function(result_str){
        result_array=result_str.split('*****');
          $("#MerryParentInitial").val(result_array[0]);
          $("#MerryParentName").val(result_array[1]); 
          $("#MerryParentLandline").val(result_array[2]);
          $("#MerryParentMobile").val(result_array[3]); 
          $("#MerryParentAddress").val(result_array[4]);
          $("#MerryParentStateId").val(result_array[5]);
          state=result_array[5];
          txt_str="state_id="+state;
          $.get("/students/getcities",txt_str,function(result){
            $("#MerryParentCityId").html(result).show();
            $("#MerryParentCityId").val(result_array[6]);
          });
          $("#MerryParentPostalCode").val(result_array[7]);
        });
      });

       $("#MerryParentStateId").change(function(){
        state=$(this).val();
        txt_str="state_id="+state;
        $.get("/students/getcities",txt_str,function(result){
            $("#MerryParentCityId").html(result).show();
        });
       });
 });
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="header">
            <?php 
               echo $this->element('logo');
               echo $this->element('navbar');
              ?>
    </div> <!-- finish div header -->
    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <div id="content1">
            <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
            </div>
            <div id="content2">
                <?php 
                       echo $this->Html->link($this->Html->image("admission_open.gif",array("alt"=>"admissions")),
                                "/students/add",array('escape'=>false));  //if escape is false, admission_open.gif 

displays, otherwise only link <img src="/merry_flowers/img/admission_open.gif" alt="admissions"/> displays.
                          echo $this->Html->image("contact_us.gif", $options=array()); 
                    ?>  
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>  <!--finish div content-->
        <div id="footer"> 
            &copy;  2011 Merry Flowers Montessori | Designed by VRI Web
        </div>
   </div><!--div container finish-->
</body>
</html>
```

The following is the view source code of default.ctp after all the corrections (the layout page in cakephp).

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 

Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />   <title>
        Merry Flowers Montessori        Home    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/cake.generic.css" /><link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/navbar.css" /><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script><script type="text/javascript" src="/js/swfobject.js"></script>   <script type="text/javascript">
       //var j=jQuery.noConflict();
      $(document).ready(function(){
          $("#MerryParentEmail").change(function(){

        //txt=$("#MerryParentEmail").val();
        email_id=$("#MerryParentEmail").serialize();
        //alert(txt);
        $.post("/students/get_parent_info",email_id,function(result_str){
        result_array=result_str.split('*****');
          $("#MerryParentInitial").val(result_array[0]);
          $("#MerryParentName").val(result_array[1]); 
          $("#MerryParentLandline").val(result_array[2]);
          $("#MerryParentMobile").val(result_array[3]); 
          $("#MerryParentAddress").val(result_array[4]);
          $("#MerryParentStateId").val(result_array[5]);
          state=result_array[5];
          txt_str="state_id="+state;
          $.get("/students/getcities",txt_str,function(result){
            $("#MerryParentCityId").html(result).show();
            $("#MerryParentCityId").val(result_array[6]);
          });
          $("#MerryParentPostalCode").val(result_array[7]);
        });
      });

       $("#MerryParentStateId").change(function(){
        state=$(this).val();


txt_str="state_id="+state;
            $.get("/students/getcities",txt_str,function(result){
                $("#MerryParentCityId").html(result).show();
            });
           });
     });
     </script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="container">

    <div id="header">
            <div>
<div style="float:left; width:98%; background-color:#ffffff;">
<img src="/img/logo.png" alt="" />  </div>
<div style="float:right; width:5%; top:100%; right:10%;">
<a href="/pages/home">Home</a>  </div>

    </div><div id="menu">

    <ul id="nav">

<!--        <li><a href="/pages/home">Home</a></li>
-->         <li><a href="#">Our Program</a><ul>

        <li><a href="/pages/preschool">Preschool</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pages/kindergarten">Kindergarten</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pages/summer_camp">Summer Camp</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a><ul>

        <li><a href="/pages/about_us">Merry Flowers</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pages/tour_our_school">Tour Our School</a></li>
        <li><a href="/pages/contact_us">Contact Us</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">My Child</a><ul>
        <li><a href="/merry_parents/register">Report Card</a></li>

        </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">Events</a><ul>
        <li><a href="#">News &amp; Events</a>               <ul>
                <li><a href="/pages/sports_day">Sports Day</a></li>
                <li><a href="/pages/annual_day">Annual Day</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>

        <li><a href="/pages/list_of_holidays">List of Holidays</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a><ul>
        <li><a href="/pages/faq">FAQ</a></li>

        <li><a href="/feedbacks/add">Feedback</a></li>
        <li><a href="/forum/home">Discussion</a></li>
        </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Admissions</a><ul>
        <li><a href="/students/add">Enroll Now</a></li>
        </ul>

        </li>
    </ul><!--finish ul nav-->
   </div> <!--finish div menu-->        </div> <!-- finish div header -->
    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <div id="content1">
            <script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
swfobject.embedSWF("/main_ani.swf", "content1", "530", "300", "9.0.0",
            "", {}, {wmode : "opaque"}, {});
//]]>
</script>               </div>

                <div id="content2">
                    <a href="/students/add"><img src="/img/admission_open.gif" alt="admissions" /></a><img src="/img/contact_us.gif" alt="" />  
                </div> 
            </div>

    </div>  <!--finish div content-->
    <div id="footer"> 
        &copy;  2011 Merry Flowers Montessori | Designed by VRI Web
    </div>


 </div><!--div container finish-->
</body>

</html>
```

By the way, i'm using jquery with cakephp. Thank you.

Comment: Why do you use directory specific URL's? It should alwyas be as from the base URL ("/" is home, so "/students/get_parent_info" would be controller students, action get_parent_info

Comment: please post the error you got for this ajax code. (e.g. the error from a firebug of firefox, or the developer tool from chrome)

Comment: Marco Johannesen, i tried "/students/get_parent_info" and it is not working.

Comment: As per siwei shen's suggestion, i tried to debug it using firebug and i found 2 errors. I have updated my question with the errrors. Please take a look! thank you.

Comment: Try removing this line -> echo $scripts_for_layout; See what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check again. The issue isn't the jQuery file itself, it's in the way it's being added, possibly the .htaccess file has a conflict, or the path is set up wrong. It's trying to load an error page. Look at the preview and response in Chrome Developer Tools, specifically the response when it loads jQuery.js. You're loading your website page when you request the jQuery file. I'd need to see more of the actual code, not the view source, in order to figure out the exact issue, but the result is that jQuery isn't loading...

EDIT: Check that your jQuery file is indeed in the /js/ folder and that it is named exactly jquery.js, not jquery.latest.min.js or something along those lines. Filenames are case sensitive, so if it's jQuery.js (note the capital Q), you'll need to rename or change your code. Also open the jQuery file and make sure it's not empty (often "downloading" jQuery requires opening the file in your browser as plain text, copying all, pasting into a file, and saving that file).

EDIT2: If this is working locally but not remotely, there are 2 possible reasons. You're either missing the rewrite conditions in your .htaccess file in your public folder, or you have /localhost/ in one of your config files, either apache httpd.config or an .htaccess file, or possibly in your config.php file (called from index.php in your public folder).

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on
#
# Redirect all non-image and non-file requests to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [PT,L]
```

Example of .htaccess in your public folder, to redirect all requests whose path is not in your public folder to go to your index file instead.

Comment: Lazerblade, i have updated my post with the actual cakephp code for default.ctp and i've also added the Chrome Developer Tool's errors for jquery.js. Yes, jquery.js is in /app/webroot/js/. As u had mentioned, i did copy the jquery text from browser, pasted it on dreamweaver and saved it as jquery.js. The latest jquery.js is not a well formatted document though.

Comment: Check your html library file - typically inside your library folder. you're looking for the one that starts with "class html" as one of the first lines, might include "extends [someotherclass]". Inside there should be a function called script (assuming your echo $this->Html->script(); line is correct syntax). Does your script function include the ability to add options? If so, set an options array on your script call, like this: echo $this->Html->script('/js/jquery.js', array('type' => 'text/javascript')); That should fix ya up.

Comment: I tried what u said, /cake/libs/view/helpers/html.php's script function allows to add options. When i view source i get <script type ="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript">. Type is repeated twice here. However i'm still getting the same errors in chrome developer tools.

Comment: <strong>Error: </strong><em>JsController</em> could not be found.</p> Line 97 of your jquery.js file. It can't find the jsController, which it shouldn't even be looking for. How are you adding your swfobject.js file? You have it commented out above, but it's still showing up somehow. The error you're seeing is because it's trying to add jquery as if it were a page. Just to see if it works, change the line that echoes the jquery script to: echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>';

Comment: where did u find that error? i'm not able to see it. I'm embedding flash into my website using flash.php found in /view/helpers/. I tried echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>'; and it is still giving the same errors in chrome.

Comment: In Chrome, right-click anywhere on the page and select inspect element. That opens Chrome Developer Tools at the bottom of the page. Then click on the [Network] tab. Then hit refresh in your browser at the top. You'll see all of the network requests for resources. Click on the one for jquery.js, you'll see the error information. SO is going to start complaining about all of the comments, so if you need further help, you can email me at lazerblade at hotmail dot com.

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP has a feature where it will generate its urls nicely. It's very easy to use
see [HTML Helper URL](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/html.html#HtmlHelper%3a%3aurl).

Your jQuery issue I believe isn't related to CakePHP.
My guess would either be your jQuery file link is invalid or your jQuery context is broken. Hard to tell.

EDIT: After seeing your page, im guessing that the problem is either.

- You are adding a full HTML document into each of the .ctp templates. This only needs to be in the default.ctp
- Or you are loading your complete page again with Ajax, whilst within your current page.

Comment: i have uploaded jquery.js to the /app/webroot/js folder and I can see it is there in the remote server.

Comment: Then use `echo $this->Html->script('jquery');` to add it to your .ctp file.

Comment: thats what i've done. The code in my question is the view source code from the browser. Initially i had put the cakephp code, and then i changed it to the view source code coz' quite often ppl are requesting for the view source code.

Comment: Are you using any other javascript libraries that might conflict with jQuerys '$' ?

Comment: I was having prototype.js in /app/webroot/js but now i've deleted that. I only have jquery.js, swfobject.js and faq.js. However, i'm still getting the same errors.

Comment: Either way, im pretty sure the specific error isn't actually related it CakePHP itself, and from what you have said and the code you have posted. I don't think I can tell you what the problem is.
I wish you good luck in your hunt though.

Comment: please take a look at my website at http://www.merryflowers.com with firebug on. U will be able to see the above errors.

Comment: Ah dude. You have multiple doctypes on your page. It looks like you are loading an entire page within a single page.
Take a look at my site [codebin](http://codebin.me) to see the source difference.

Comment: Ok, i see that too. I will try to modify that and get back here. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: After reading Arcynum's answer again, i removed all the redundant html, header and body tags from the ctp files. I've updated my question with the latest view source code. However, i'm still getting the same errors. This is driving me insane. :(

Answer (score 1):

The most probable answer could be the way you have linked your jquery file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
```

Check firebug > Scripts and see what the result of jquery.js is. If I guessed it right, `jquery.js` is not returning the `jquery` code instead returning either 404 or something.

Comment: yes, coz' jquery.js is inside /app/webroot/js/ folder as in http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1589/script.

Comment: Sorry, missed this answer when I was reading and basically duplicated it. Though not an answer to the problem, it, like my post, points to the culprit much better than other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are sending the request is

```
$.post("../students/get_parent_info" ... );
```

Which seem more like a **directory traversing** not a link. Even though it might seem to work in a phase, you should use this. You might have to provide direct link like

```
$.post("http://domain.com/students/get_parent_info", ... );
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok with lazerblade's guidance, I found the problem, there was no jquery.js in public_html/merry_flowers/js and www/merry_flowers/js folders. Now after adding jquery.js into those folders i'm not getting any errors in jquery.js's network response (chrome developer tool's network) anymore and jquery.js is of type application/javascript in network. However, my jquery functions are not working yet. So, i have to look into that now.

thanks a tonnes to all of you guys. YOur help is priceless!